# Understanding .text section of PE executable

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering, cil, portable-executable

I'm trying to create a simple CIL code decompiler. I've managed to load headers and sections correctly, now I'm struggling with the .text section.

Here is my test app:

```
using System;

namespace Sample2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int localVarriableOne = 123;
            int localVarriableTwo = 654;

            Console.WriteLine(localVarriableOne + localVarriableTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

The .text section header tells me that `PointerToRawData = 0x0200`, which is what I expected. Now when I try to skip to that offset I encounter weird characters (marked red), which are not what I expected. I thought that I'm supposed to encounter Method Header, tiny or big, but it doesn't seem like I was correct. The method header is supposed to have 2nd lowest bit set not depending on header type.

[image: XVI]

However, I managed to find my CIL code that I expected (marked blue)! Using CIL opcodes from my reference, I saw that the code matches my expectations:

```
ldc.i4.s 123
stloc.0
ldc.i4 456
stloc.1
...
```

Now I'm confused. For sure there is something before my method declaration but I can't find anything about .text section. If someone could give me any clue, I'd be really pleased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET assemblies don't use the traditional `text` segment to store their .NET code - only natively compiled code goes there. Instead they use special CLR structures inside the PE that only .NET assemblies have.

One of the "optional" headers in the PE file is the CLR Runtime Header, which has all the key information about where .NET-specific structures are located within the PE.

For more details on this, download the latest PE specification [("Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg463119.aspx) from msdn.com.

For even more detailed explanations on how the many pieces of .NET executable code and corresponding data are organized in the PE, get [Serge Lidin's book on the .NET assembler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463).